# Google Cloud Functions certificate doesn't match domain name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-functions, telegram-bot

I want to use my Google Cloud Function as a webhook endpoint for a [Telegram bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) - so that Telegram server makes a request to my function every time there's an update that I need to reply to. [(Here's a full guide they provide for this)](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks). I have set up such a webhook at a GCF provided address, which looks like `https://us-central1-project-name-123456.cloudfunctions.net/processUpdate` (where `processUpdate` is the name of my function).

However, it looks like Telegram doesn't work with my function because of a problem with certificate. They `@CanOfWormsBot` created to troubleshoot this provides an error message:

> ⛔️ This verified certificate appears to be invalid
>   https://us-central1-project-name-123456.cloudfunctions.net/processUpdate
>
> Your CN (Common Name) or SAN (Subject Alternative Name) appear not to match your domain name, please verify you're setting the correct domain for the certificate.
>
> CERTIFICATE:
>
> Common Name(CN): misc.google.com
>
> Issuer: Google Internet Authority G3
>
> Alternative Names(SAN): Too many SANS to be shown here.
>
> Issued: 18/06/2019
>   Expires: 10/09/2019

What's the root cause of this issue? Does it mean that Google misconfigured certificate they use for `cloudfunctions.net`? Can I fix this by configuring my cloud function?

Comment: Google does not provide custom domain names for Google Cloud Functions. Therefore, the SSL certificate that Cloud Functions provides the client does not have your domain name in the Subject or SAN fields. If all you did was map a CNAME to the Cloud Functions URL, that won't work for HTTPS.

Comment: For functions that need a custom domain name and HTTPS, I recommend looking at Google Cloud Run or App Engine.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't need **my** domain name in the certificate - I need domain name that my function is on, `cloudfunctions.net`, which belongs to Google.